# How to specify a hidden email address when signing up with Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-integration

In the past, whenever I signed up to some web app with Facebook, I got the option to give them a custom email address instead of revealing my Facebook email address.

It now seems to be gone:

[image]

There used to be a dropdown allowing me to select a "secret" address. Is there really no longer a way to sign up with Facebook without giving them my Facebook address?

I use a custom address for every website so that I know who leaked it to spammers and have a trivial way to permanently block it; that's why I'd rather not reveal my Facebook email address.

Comment: I believe they have removed the functionality completely. I don't have a source, so I'm leaving my observation as a comment instead of an answer...

Comment: @romkyns you're totally right... i'm deleting that original comment because it's a mess of misreading things and bad google searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is apparently an [intentional](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/320226311352716) change in the new auth dialog, which is now in the process of being rolled out to all users and all applications.  You may want to avoid adding any apps that require this information.

Comment: If using the app requires your email, they should ask for it and explain why. If it doesn't, some users won't grant the permissions and it'll hurt them. Developers need to make that tradeoff (as do users)